# Error message when compiling a stack program in C language

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I am wrote a stack example but it shows a error message when compiled.

In switch case 4: exit (); this line is the problem : think

```
64  9   C:\Users\pavilion 15\OneDrive\Documents\stack.cpp   [Error] return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
```

This is the error message I saw when compiling this code. Can some one please help me to solve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 5

int stack[MAX];
int top = -1;

void push(int);
int pop();
void display();

main(){

    int choice,num;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        printf("1.Push\n");
        printf("2.Pop\n");
        printf("3.Display\n");
        printf("Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter a number");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                push(num);
                break;
            case 2:
                 num = pop();
                 break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("invalid input");
        }
    }

}


void push(int element){

    if(top == MAX-1 ){
        printf("Stack OverFlow");
        return;
    }
    top = top +1;
    stack[top]=element;
}

void pop(){
    int element;
    if(top == -1){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    element = stack[top];
    top = top - 1;
    printf("%d has been deleted", element);
    return element;
}

void display(){
    int i;
    if(top==-1){
        printf("stack is empty!");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=top;i>0;i--)
    printf("%d\n", stack[i]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't return a value from a `void` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `int pop()` but you defined `void pop()`, and inside the definition you try to `return element`.

Now this would normally lead to an error when you do `num = pop()` since it wouldn't be able to find the correct definition for the function you forward declared but the compiler stops earlier since the function `void pop()` is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a value from a `void` function.

```
void pop(){
    int element;
    if(top == -1){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    element = stack[top];
    top = top - 1;
    printf("%d has been deleted", element);
    return element;
}
```

needs to be `int pop()`

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an element from `pop()` - it's `void` (no return type)...

... Exactly like the error message says!

The easiest fix is to make it return an `int`, but then you need a special return code to indicate an error.
Alternatively: `int pop(int *v)` - returns 0 on failure or 1 on success, and populates `v`.

Comment: Read the whole answer: once you make `pop` return an `int` you have to address your error case (currently just `return;`) - YoIf you say your are returning an `int` from a function then you  always have to return an `int` from it.